# Refresh browser once when resizing past point - JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am absolutely stuck on this, so i hope you guys can help!

Basically i'm trying to refresh the browser if the browser gets resized from 960px or above to 959px or less.

I want this to happen only once, but if the browser gets resized back up to 960px or above, and then again gets resized back down, to refresh again...

Not really sure if that makes a whole load of sense but here's what i have so far!

```
 function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();
        var i = 0;

        if (windowsize > 959 && i==0){
            var i = 1;
        }
        else if (windowsize <= 959 && i==1) {
           location.reload();
           var i = 0;      

        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

Any help would be super awesome! Cheeeers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
var i = 0;

$(function () {
    $(window).on("resize", function () {
        var windowsize = $(this).width();
        if (windowsize > 959 && i === 0) {
            i = 1;
        } else if (windowsize <= 959 && i == 1) {
            location.reload();
            i = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need () around window in the first line of the function.

```
var i = 0;
function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $(window).width();

    if (windowsize > 959 && i==0){
        i = 1;
    }
    else if (windowsize <= 959 && i==1) {
       location.reload();
       i = 0;      
    }
}
// Execute on load
checkWidth();
// Bind event listener
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

Also, if you don't mind my asking, what is your goal for this? I assume you're trying to do some sort of responsive design, if so you should look into using CSS

```
@media (max-width:959px) { styles for when its under 959px wide go here }
```

This will turn it into a pure CSS method of handling responsiveness and might not need you to do anything with javascript for it.

Comment: i've done my responsiveness is css, i have some animation on larger screen sizes which breaks the layout when the width goes below 960px, also the script still doesn't do anything

Comment: move your var i = 0 outside the function so its in global scope, its being re-initialized every time you call the function, so it will never be <= 959 And i == 1 and remove the var i = 1 and var i = 0 inside your if/else statements, I'll update my comment to reflect these changes.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $(window).width();
    var reload = false;

    if (windowsize > 959){
        reload = true;
    }
    else if (windowsize <= 959) {
        reload = true;
    }
    if(reload){
      location.reload();
    }
}
// Bind event listener
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

Comment: this refreshes everytime the page is resizes rather than just the once

Answer (score 0):

I used the final solution from this and it works fine when I move from 'desktop' mode (575 pixel width or more) to 'mobile', but when moving from the 'mobile' mode (574 pixel width or less) it does not fully reload/refresh the page. Seems the javascript for menus and a temporary viewport width line are not reloading fully, though all page contents are reloading correctly.

Is there some way to ensure a full reload in both directions? I might have the 
javascript in the wrong places?  Manual refresh puts everything where it belongs and restores function of all.

This is in the header of all pages via an include file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 0;
    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $(window).width();
        if (windowsize > 574 && i==0){
            i = 1;
        }
        else if (windowsize <= 574 && i==1) {
            location.reload();
                i = 0;      
        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
</script>
```

And the javascript for the menus is just above the copyright include file I use:

```
    <script src="/js/jquery.dlmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).resize(function(){    
            $(function() {
                $( '#dl-menu' ).dlmenu({
                    animationClasses : { classin : 'dl-animate-in-2', classout : 'dl-animate-out-2' }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And the viewport dimensions javascript is included in the copyright:

```
<div id="dimensions">
    <script type="text/javascript">
       <!--
            var viewportwidth;
            var viewportheight;
            // the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight

            if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined')
            {
                viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
                viewportheight = window.innerHeight
            }
            // IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)
            else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
                && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
                'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0)
            {
                viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
                viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
            }
            // older versions of IE
            else
            {
                viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
                viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
            }
            document.write('<p>Your viewport width is '+viewportwidth+'x'+viewportheight+'</p>');
            <!-- document.write('<p>Your screen width is '+window.screen.width+'</p>);  -->
        //-->
    </script>
</div>
```